# Is my second equation right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The difference between two integers is 3. Twice the smaller is equal to five less than half the larger.

Let $x =$ the larger integer.
Let $y =$ the other integer

1st equation: $$x - y = 3$$

2nd equation: $$2y = \frac{x}{2}-5 $$

Comment: In future, use brackets to help make things clearer! Also, they look right to me.

Comment: Yes it is. Good work on setting up the equations.

Answer (score 3):

Your equations are very much correct. This is a linear system of two equations in two unknowns, which you can solve for.
$$\begin{cases} x-y=3 \\ 2y=\frac{x}{2}-5 \\ \end{cases}$$
I do not like dealing with fractions, so I will multiply by $2$ on both sides in the second equation.
$$\begin{cases} x-y=3 \\ 4y=x-10 \\ \end{cases}$$
Isolate $x$ in both equations.
$$\begin{cases} x=y+3 \\ x=4y+10 \\ \end{cases}$$
Equate the expressions.
$$4y+10=y+3$$
$$3y=-7$$
$$y=-\frac73$$
Plug this $y$ value back in to any equation.
$$x=-\frac{7}{3}+3$$
$$x=-\frac{7}{3}+\frac{9}{3}$$
$$x=\frac23$$
There is one solution to this system of equations, which is:
$$x=\frac23, \ y=-\frac73$$
I do not know why I did not get integer solutions, but I checked with WolframAlpha, and my solution is correct. Your equations are definitely correct though.